# How to identify in selenium IDE an input followed by a label?

Tags: selenium

I have to identify a check-box using the label which follows it.
the code is the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" id="email-100-100" name="email-100-100">
<label for="email-100-100" class="firefinder-match">Email me when someone asks me to set a flag</label>
<br>
</td>
```

I tried

Target://following-sibling::label[text()="Email me when someone asks me to set a flag"] 
Target://preceding-sibling::label[text()="Email me when someone asks me to set a flag"]

but in both cases selenium finds the text of label but not the check-box.

Could somebody help me in this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Target://label[text()="Email me when someone asks me to set a flag"]/../input[@type='checkbox']
```

It will work as long as the containing element of the label and checkbox only has one checkbox in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a label that contains text, which is useful for a partial match.    In my case I had something like this:

```
<label for="blah">
     <input name="blah" id="blah" type="checkbox" />
     Store Locator Plus
</label>
```

The accepted solution worked for the specific example cited but requires an exact match.  Since this comes up on the top of search results I figured I'd present the partial-match solution here as well.

For Selenium IDE you can set a target like this:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Store Locator Plus')]//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

The contains function was required because the label text had an HTML element as well which thwarted the //label[text()='Store Locator Plus'] target.